# Intellisense not using project typescript version

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

Is there a way to determine what version of TypeScript IntelliSense is using in VS2017?
We have a web project that is using TypeScript 2.1 (in project properties) and has the following tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": false
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "ScriptsApp",
    "Scripts",
    "ScriptsModels"
  ]
}
```

We can get the solution to compile the TypeScript files without error or warning, but we always get Intellisense errors.

In the build log I can see msbuild is using the 2.1 version.
If I change the version to TypeScript 2.6, I get the same errors in build en IntelliSence. So it looks like IntelliSence is using TypeScript 2.6.

Is there a way to set the IntelliSense TypeScript version?

I have Visual Studio 2017 (15.4.4) installed with Typescript 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 and 2.6.

Comment: The TypeScript intellisense is shipped with the TypeScript version, in the VS 2017 15.2 and earlier versions, we can go to Tools > Options > Text Editor >JavaScript/TypeScript > IntelliSense, change Use TypeScript version to your desired version, now we go right click the project name>Properties>TypeScript Build>TypeScript Version to select the desired version, check https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Updating-TypeScript-in-Visual-Studio-2017#setting-typescript-versions-in-visual-studio-2017-version-153, we cannot choose another TypeScript intellisense, sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT : we are setting the desired version to 2.1 in the project properties (VS 15.4.4), and I can verify msbuild is using this version of TypeScript. But it looks like intellisense is still using TypeScript 2.6. 
We get multiple TypeScript errors in the "intellisense" view of the error window but none in the build error list.
If we set TypeScript to 2.6, we get the same errors also for the build.

Comment: How did you know the intellisense is using the TypeScript 2.6? Please try to uninstall the TypeScript 2.6, then test this again, it can help us to check if the TypeScript 2.6 intellisense caused this issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
I uninstalled Typescript 2.6 and no longer have the errors. So I'm pretty sure Typescript 2.6 is used for Intellisense. After a reinstall, the errors returned.

Comment: Thank you for your update, you can also go to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues and report this issue to the TypeScript Product Team to seek for a better support then share the link as reply, that will help other community members who meet the same issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: I was not sure if it is a TypeScript issue or Visual Studio issue. 
But I will report it on the TypeScript github.

Comment: I've created an issue on the TypeScript GitHub.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20438

Comment: Thanks for your sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved in VS 15.5.x. 
See: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20438